# How to make shiny app deployed on the shiny server update automatically if local dataset is updated

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a simple shiny app for local dataset "orders" that works fine locally and has been deployed on the server. My question is: when I updated data, the app updated too locally, but didn't update on the server, could anyone tell me the way to make the app on the shiny server update automatically if local dataset is updated?

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
        plotOutput("hist")
        )
```

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
        fileReaderData <- reactiveFileReader(500,session,
                                             "orders.xlsx", readxl::read_excel)
        output$hist <- renderPlot({
                data<-fileReaderData()
                data%>%group_by(date=as.Date(date))%>%summarise(count=sum(ordersum,na.rm=T))%>%
                        ggplot(aes(x=date,y=count))+geom_line(color=brewer.pal(7,"Set1")[2])+
                        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month")


        })

}
```

```
deployApp(appDir = "/Users/jefflian/aaaa")
```

Comment: Remote storage may be useful as described here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Comment: you can use dropbox api. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580850/reading-raw-data-in-r-to-be-saved-as-rdata-file-using-the-dropbox-api)